# expressJS 4.x + vhost + SSL/HTTPS

Tags: node.js, ssl, express, https, virtualhost

I am not too familiar with SSL so I was wondering what I am missing to make vhost + expressjs as well as ssl all connected. My code works for virtualhost+ expressjs but not https. 
Port is definitely open.

```js
var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync("ca.key"),
  cert: fs.readFileSync("ca.crt")
}

var main = express();
if (!module.parent) main.use(logger('dev'));

main.get('/', function(req, res){
  // DO SOMETHING
});


var app = module.exports = express();
app.use(vhost('myappblahbblah.com', main));

var server = https.createServer(options, app);
server.listen(443);
```

Comment: What are the error messages are you seeing?

Comment: I don't see any error messages. chrome only says that it took too long to respond. I know that it's listening because I get a result back if I have listen(port, function() {console.log("listening")})

Comment: Have you tried logging anything in the app to try to see how far it gets?

Comment: I had console print out for the listen function and it did print out so I am guessing the whole code was run.

Answer (score 0):

Use `server.addContext(hostname, context)`, which is shown in `tls` module, whereas `https.Server` inherits from `tls.Server`.

If you don't know how to actually implement it, I wrote a very small package [vhttps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vhttps) that did the work for you. Checkout its `README.md` about how to use it with `vhost` and `express`.